# shortcut icon - where are they hidden in html code?

Tags: html, css, shortcut

Most shortcut icon are presented in HTML like this:

```
<link rel="Shortcut icon" href="url" />
```

but many sites don't have shortcut icon in their html code but still chrome is showing me icons on tabs. How they made it? I want to download icons from different websites but I don't know where my crawler should look for them. Examples of websites where I can find it:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0976470705?tag=lessolearn01-20&camp=0&creative=0&linkCode=as4&creativeASIN=0976470705&adid=0E34NG800FT9HMWYP4D6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976470705)

http://www.startuplessonslearned.com/2008/10/lean-startups-vs-lean-companies.html

Comment: It's called a `favicon`, look for that `rel` attribute.

Comment: For `favicon.ico` there is no tag required. Just dropped in the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second page give as example, the tag is

```
<link href='http://www.startuplessonslearned.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon'
type='image/x-icon'/>
```

The attribute specification `rel="icon"` is practically synonymous with `rel="shortcut icon"`.

On the first page, there is no tag that affects favicon issue, but at the *server root* there is a file with the name `favicon.ico`, i.e. http://www.amazon.com/favicon.ico, and that’s what browsers use, by convention. Putting an icon under such a name at the server root thus makes the `link` elements redundant, provided that you want to use the same icon for all pages. Of course, not everyone can put files at the server root.

Answer (score 2):

It is known as favicon (most of times!).

For the second link you pointed to, it is :

```
<link href='http://www.startuplessonslearned.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
```

Also, it could be added in several ways. For more info read [this article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use .png file:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="x-icon" href=".directory/image.png" />
```